# Controlling the order of dequeing in the Semaphore Queue in Linux

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads, semaphore

I want to implement code where I am suppose to assign several "priority numbers" to different threads. Some of the threads may WAIT on the same semaphore. Say the threads are queued on semaphore S and another thread performs a sem_post on the semaphore S. As soon as the sem_post is executed, I want that thread which has the highest "priority number" in the semaphore S queue to gain access to the semaphore and not any other thread. As far as I can understand, there is no direct way to achieve this as the thread that will be chosen for access can be any one of the elements of the queue (and not necessarily FIFO etc.).  Infact, I tried increasing the pthread priority of the threads, but I realised it doesnt work either. Can someone please guide me how to implement this design of controlling the semaphore queue manually in C. Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two approaches:

- Use a [condition variable](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/pthread_cond_wait.html) to "wake some or all waiters," who will sort out priority release themselves; or
- Use (realtime) signals to "wake a single, specific waiter" in priority order

In each case, the semaphore has at least a [*mutex*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html), a *value*, and some bookkeeping.  If the *value* is below zero, its absolute value is the number of waiters (e.g., value == -3 means 3 threads are waiting).

### Condition Variable Approach

The semaphore tracks the number of waiters at any given priority, as well as the number of waiters *released* at any given priority.  In pseudo-C:

```
typedef struct priority_sem_s {
  int              value;     // if negative, abs(sem->value) == no. of waiting threads
  pthread_mutex_t  mutex;
  pthread_cond_t   cv;
  int              n_waiting[N_PRIORITIES];  // no. waiting (blocked) at each priority
  int              n_released[N_PRIORITIES]; // no. waiters released (unblocked) at each priority
} priosem_t;

void post(priosem_t *sem):
  lock(sem->mutex);
  sem->value++;

  if (sem->value <= 0 && prio_waiting_is_NOT_empty(sem)):
    // someone was waiting; release one of the highest prio
    int prio = fetch_highest_prio_waiting(sem);
    sem->prio_waiting[prio]--;
    sem->prio_released[prio]++;
    cond_broadcast(sem->cv, sem->mutex);

  unlock(sem->mutex);

void wait(priosem_t *sem, int prio):
  lock(sem->mutex);
  sem->value--;

  if (sem->value < 0):
    // get in line
    sem->prio_waiting[prio]++;
    while (sem->prio_released[prio] < 0):
      cond_wait(sem->cv, sem->mutex);
    // ok to leave
    sem->prio_released[prio]--;

  unlock(sem->mutex);
```

**Advantages:**  Can be shared across processes (implemented in shared memory).

**Disadvantages:** Awakens every waiter to release just one.  Martin James suggests one conditional variable per priority, which would reduce "unnecessary" wake-ups at the cost of more synchronization primitives.

### Signal Approach

Use [sigsuspend](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/sigsuspend.html) and a [realtime signal](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html) with a noop handler to pause and resume waiters.  In pseudo-C:

```
typedef struct priority_sem_s {
  int              value;    // if negative, abs(value) == no. of waiting threads
  pthread_mutex_t  mutex;
  void            *waiting;  // ordered list of [priority, thread-id] pairs
} priosem_t;

void post(priosem_t *sem):
  lock(sem->mutex);
  sem->value++;

  if (sem->value <= 0 && waiting_queue_is_NOT_empty(sem)):
    pthread_t tid = pop_highest_prio_waiter(sem);
    pthread_kill(tid, SIGRTMIN+n);

  unlock(sem->mutex);

void wait(priosem_t *sem, int prio):
  // XXX --> PRECONDITION:  SIGRTMIN+n is SIG_BLOCK'd <-- XXX
  // XXX --> PRECONDITION:  SIGRTMIN+n has a no-op handler installed <-- XXX
  lock(sem->mutex);
  sem->value--;

  if (sem->value < 0):
    // get in line
    add_me_to_wait_list(sem, pthread_self(), prio);
    unlock(sem->mutex);
    sigsuspend(full_mask_except_sigrtmin_plus_n);
    return;  // OK!

  unlock(sem->mutex);
```

**Advantages:**  Conceptually simpler; no unnecessary wake-ups.

**Disadvantages:** Cannot be shared across processes.  An available realtime signal must be chosen or dynamically selected (look for an unmasked signal with SIG_DFL disposition?) and masked as early as possible.

Comment: +1 for actual code, (though I think that's very err.. 'brave':)

Comment: @MartinJames, you can say 'foolhardy' :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to build your own 'PrioritySemaphore', (PS), class, with post() and wait(priority) methods.  You need a mutex to protect the internal data, a 'totalCount' int and an array[priority] of structs that contain a semaphore for threads to wait on and a 'PriorityCount' int.

wait(priority): lock the mutex. If totalCount>0, dec it, unlock the mutex and return.  If totalCount=0, index the array with(priority), inc the PriorityCount, unlock the mutex and wait on the semaphore.

post(): lock the mutex.  If totalCount=0, inc it, unlock the mutex and return. If totalCount>0, iterate the array from the highest-priority end, looking for a non-zero PriorityCount.  If none is found, inc totalCount, unlock the mutex and return.  If a non-zero PriorityCount is found, dec it, signal the semaphore at that priority, unlock the mutex and return.

Comment: IIUC, where you say "semaphore" above, I think in pthreads we'd say "condition variable."  I'd suggest a "PendingReleaseCount" per priority slot — incremented upon post() iff a waiter is found, and decremented in wait() *after* being woken up — if several waiters can arrive at the same priority.  Otherwise you've a race wherein the signal from a new post() could "get lost."

Comment: Can you please explain in a little more detail. I feel the solution proposed above has a race condition in the wait function. The function releases the mutex and then waits on the semaphore. Moreover, Say a thread comes first and acquires a PrioritySemaphore (with initial value of 1, making it a mutex) as implemented above, then say another thread queues on the semaphore. When the former exits the critical section and calls the "post" function, the totalcount=0 so the semaphore gets unlocked but the latter thread does not gain control. We would need one more call to "post" to start the latter.

Comment: @wang 'The function releases the mutex and then waits on the semaphore'.  Sure. If it waited on the semaphore before releasing the mutex, the class would deadlock because the mutex would never get released.  Still thinking about your other point:)

Comment: @wang - second point - you want a way to initialize the PS upon creation, yes?  I must admit that I only considered a PS with an initial count of 0.

Answer (score 0):

I had to develop a semaphore structure with the following characteristics:

1. there's a critical section where up to `Capacity` threads can enter and execute simultaneously. After execution threads exit the critical section;
2. when the semaphore reaches its maximum capacity, and execution queue is filled: threads in the queue are put to sleep and are woken up when other threads exit the critical section;
3. the execution queue has FIFO semantics;
4. there's a notification mechanism that inform waiting threads of their position in the queue;
5. Only threads that entered the critical section are allowed to exit it.

Points 1-2 typically describe a theoretical [semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)) datatype, while points 3-4 mandates other behavior/API constraints and functionalities. Without too much surprise such structure can be built with just *mutex* and *condition variable* primitives, even though semaphore is often misrepresented as a synchronization primitive itself. It follows a C++11 implementation that can be also ported to any language/environment that provides the above primitives. The implementation is not completely trivial, due to requirement of the notify mechanism to not keep busy the semaphore lock. Custom priority and priority editing has not been implemented because I didn't need scheduler-like features, but they should be possible too.

*Semaphore.h*

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
#include <list>

namespace usr
{
    typedef std::function<void(unsigned processIndex)> SemaphoreNotifier;

    class Semaphore;

    class SemaphoreToken final
    {
        friend class Semaphore;
    public:
        SemaphoreToken();
    private:
        SemaphoreToken(Semaphore &semaphore);
    private:
        void Invalidate();
    private:
        Semaphore *Parent;
        std::thread::id ThreadId;
    };

    class SemaphoreCounter final
    {
        friend class Semaphore;
    public:
        SemaphoreCounter();
    private:
        void Increment();
    public:
        unsigned GetCount() const { return m_count; }
    private:
        unsigned m_count;
    };

    class Semaphore final
    {
        class Process
        {
        public:
            Process(unsigned index);
        public:
            void Wait();
            void Set();
            void Decrement();
            void Detach();
        public:
            bool IsDetached() const { return m_detached; }
            unsigned GetIndex() const { return m_index; }
        private:
            std::mutex m_mutex;
            unsigned m_index;                   // Guarded by m_mutex
            bool m_detached;                    // Guarded by m_mutex
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> m_lock;
            std::condition_variable m_cond;
        };
    public:
        Semaphore(unsigned capacity = 1);
    public:
        SemaphoreToken Enter();
        SemaphoreToken Enter(SemaphoreCounter &counter, unsigned &id);
        SemaphoreToken Enter(const SemaphoreNotifier &notifier);
        SemaphoreToken Enter(const SemaphoreNotifier &notifier, SemaphoreCounter &counter, unsigned &id);
        bool TryEnter(SemaphoreToken &token);
        bool TryEnter(SemaphoreCounter &counter, unsigned &id, SemaphoreToken &token);
        void Exit(SemaphoreToken &token);
    private:
        bool enter(bool tryEnter, const SemaphoreNotifier &notifier, SemaphoreCounter *counter, unsigned &id, SemaphoreToken &token);
    private:
        // Disable copy constructor and assign operator
        Semaphore(const Semaphore &);
        Semaphore & operator=(const Semaphore &);
    public:
        unsigned GetCapacity() const { return m_capacity; }
    private:
        mutable std::mutex m_mutex;
        unsigned m_capacity;
        unsigned m_leftCapacity;               // Guarded by m_mutex
        std::list<Process *> m_processes;      // Guarded by m_mutex
    };
}
```

*Semaphore.cpp*

```cpp
#include "Semaphore.h"
#include <cassert>
#include <limits>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
using namespace usr;

Semaphore::Semaphore(unsigned capacity)
{
    if (capacity == 0)
        throw runtime_error("Capacity must not be zero");

    m_capacity = capacity;
    m_leftCapacity = capacity;
}

SemaphoreToken Semaphore::Enter()
{
    unsigned id;
    SemaphoreToken token;
    enter(false, nullptr, nullptr, id, token);
    return token;
}

SemaphoreToken Semaphore::Enter(SemaphoreCounter &counter, unsigned &id)
{
    SemaphoreToken token;
    enter(false, nullptr, &counter, id, token);
    return token;
}

SemaphoreToken Semaphore::Enter(const SemaphoreNotifier &notifier)
{
    unsigned id;
    SemaphoreToken token;
    enter(false, notifier, nullptr, id, token);
    return token;
}

SemaphoreToken Semaphore::Enter(const SemaphoreNotifier &notifier,
    SemaphoreCounter &counter, unsigned &id)
{
    SemaphoreToken token;
    enter(false, notifier, &counter, id, token);
    return token;
}

bool Semaphore::TryEnter(SemaphoreToken &token)
{
    unsigned id;
    return enter(true, nullptr, nullptr, id, token);
}

bool Semaphore::TryEnter(SemaphoreCounter &counter, unsigned &id, SemaphoreToken &token)
{
    return enter(true, nullptr, &counter, id, token);
}

bool Semaphore::enter(bool tryEnter, const SemaphoreNotifier &notifier,
    SemaphoreCounter *counter, unsigned &id, SemaphoreToken &token)
{
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(m_mutex);
    if (counter != nullptr)
    {
        id = counter->GetCount();
        counter->Increment();
    }

    if (m_leftCapacity > 0)
    {
        // Semaphore is availabile without accessing queue
        assert(m_processes.size() == 0);
        m_leftCapacity--;
    }
    else
    {
        if (tryEnter)
            return false;

        Process process((unsigned)m_processes.size());
        unsigned previousIndex = numeric_limits<unsigned>::max();
        m_processes.push_back(&process);

        // Release semaphore unlock
        lock.unlock();

    NotifyAndWait:
        unsigned index = process.GetIndex();
        if (notifier != nullptr && index != 0 && index != previousIndex)
        {
            try
            {
                // Notify the caller on progress
                notifier(index);
            }
            catch (...)
            {
                // Retake Semaphore lock
                lock.lock();

                // Remove the failing process
                auto found = std::find(m_processes.begin(), m_processes.end(), &process);
                auto it = m_processes.erase(found);
                for (; it != m_processes.end(); it++)
                {
                    // Decrement following processes
                    auto &otherProcess = **it;
                    otherProcess.Decrement();
                    otherProcess.Set();
                }

                // Rethrow. NOTE: lock will be unlocked by RAII
                throw;
            }
            previousIndex = index;
        }

        process.Wait();
        if (!process.IsDetached())
            goto NotifyAndWait;
    }

    token = SemaphoreToken(*this);
    return true;
}

void Semaphore::Exit(SemaphoreToken &token)
{
    if (this != token.Parent || token.ThreadId != this_thread::get_id())
        throw runtime_error("Exit called from wrong semaphore or thread");

    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        if (m_processes.size() == 0)
        {
            m_leftCapacity++;
        }
        else
        {
            auto front = m_processes.front();
            m_processes.pop_front();
            front->Detach();
            front->Set();

            for (auto process : m_processes)
            {
                process->Decrement();
                process->Set();
            }
        }

        token.Invalidate();
    }
}

SemaphoreToken::SemaphoreToken() :
    Parent(nullptr)
{
}

SemaphoreToken::SemaphoreToken(usr::Semaphore &semaphore) :
    Parent(&semaphore),
    ThreadId(this_thread::get_id())
{
}

void SemaphoreToken::Invalidate()
{
    Parent = nullptr;
    ThreadId = thread::id();
}

SemaphoreCounter::SemaphoreCounter()
    : m_count(0)
{
}

void SemaphoreCounter::Increment()
{
    m_count++;
}

Semaphore::Process::Process(unsigned index) :
    m_index(index),
    m_detached(false),
    m_lock(m_mutex)
{
}

void Semaphore::Process::Wait()
{
    m_cond.wait(m_lock);
}

void Semaphore::Process::Set()
{
    m_cond.notify_one();
}

void Semaphore::Process::Decrement()
{
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(m_mutex);
    assert(m_index > 0);
    m_index--;
}

void Semaphore::Process::Detach()
{
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(m_mutex);
    assert(m_index == 0);
    m_detached = true;
}
```

I tested it with the following sample code:

```cpp
SemaphoreCounter counter;
Semaphore semaphore(4);  // Up to 4 threads can execute simultaneously

vector<shared_ptr<thread>> threads;
int threadCount = 300;
for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++)
{
    threads.push_back(std::make_shared<thread>([&semaphore, &counter]
    {
        unsigned threadId;
        auto token = semaphore.Enter([&threadId](unsigned index) {
            cout << "Thread " << threadId << " has " << index << " processes ahead before execution" << endl;
        }, counter, threadId);

        cout << "EXECUTE Thread " << threadId << endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(15ms);
        semaphore.Exit(token);
    }));
}

for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++)
    threads[i]->join();
```